# Python pyodbc multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, syntax-error, pyodbc

Getting a SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement when trying to use

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;Port=88;User ID=Me;Password=MyPassword')
```

in the IDLE.

Expected to be able to run a statement using the cursor after connecting.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```